# Why can I bind to port 80

Tags: docker, .net-core

I've created an image with non-root user and always thought that you can't bind to ports < 1024 (I saw it in different guides and a lot of questions on StackOverflow). But for testing, I've create simple `ASP.NET Core Web API` (from template) and generated `Dockerfile` by `VS Code` (even `VS Code` thinks the same, if you generate `Dockerfile` for 5000 port it creates non-root user, but if you select 80 port then it creates image with root user).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-dotnet-configure-containers
RUN addgroup --gid 8765 appgroup
RUN adduser -u 5678 --gid 8765 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser:appgroup /app
USER appuser:appgroup

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["webapi.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "webapi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "webapi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "webapi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "webapi.dll"]
```

Then build and run it:

```
docker build . -t test
docker run --rm -it -p 5000:80 test
```

And it works perfectly, then I check result of `top` command and it outputs that `dotnet` runs as `appuser`.

Is this restriction (root access to bind < 1024 ports) not valid anymore? Is it changed by newer versions of Docker or is it related to .NET?

According to [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) documentation, `Docker` adds several `Linux` capabilities (by default). One of them is `NET_BIND_SERVICE`, which allows:

> Bind a socket to internet domain privileged ports (port numbers less than 1024).

But if I drop all capabilities by `--cap-drop=all`, it still works.

Tested on:

- Docker Desktop 3.5.2 (Mac OS / Windows 10)
- Linux Docker 20.10.7

Comment: Drop capabilities of which specific process? The command-line interface talking to the Docker daemon? It doesn't need them. The code running inside the container? If the bind is done _outside_ the container (or by telling the IP stack to remap the ports without actually directly binding), it's moot.

Comment: I'm off in speculation here, but there's also not a really great reason for the kernel to enforce `NET_BIND_SERVICE`  rules in isolated namespaces. I'd need to RTFM (or read the fine kernel source), but it wouldn't be astonishing if there was a deliberate decision not to always require that capability.

Comment: "When the user doesn’t have a primary group then the image (or the next instructions) will be run with the root group", https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that since Docker 20.03.0 you can now bind to any port even while dropping all capabilities.

See the answer here [In my Docker container, why can I still bind the port 1 without `NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65853364/in-my-docker-container-why-can-i-still-bind-the-port-1-without-net-bind-servic)